# This error occurred when the flow tried to look up records: sObject type 'ContentWorkspace' is not supported

Tags: visual-workflow, files

User goes to a LEX page with a Screen Flow component. The component executes and returns error:

```
This error occurred when the flow tried to look up records: 
     sObject type 'ContentWorkspace' is not supported.
```

The Flow has a Get Records element accessing Object `Library`

How to resolve this error message?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*N.B. `ContentWorkSpace` is the SObject used for `Libraries`*

One solution to this is to give the user `CRM Content User` permission on their User record.

[image]